# run target in ant that depends on jar

Tags: java, ant, jar, target, depends

I have a `jar` target in ant that makes a jar out of two classes that I have.  Then, I want to run this jar in another target that depends on the jar target.  Would there be an easy way to do this in ant?  I have my compile and jar targets pasted below.

```
<project>
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="." destdir="build/classes"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/KnightsTour.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="PlayTour"/>
            </manifest>
                </jar>
    </target>
</project
```

Answer (score 1):

To run a Java application, use the `java` task (see https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html for its documentation). An example from the docs:

```
<java jar="dist/test.jar" fork="true" failonerror="true" maxmemory="128m">
     <arg value="arg1"/>
     <arg value="arg2"/>
     <classpath>
       <pathelement location="dist/test.jar"/>
       <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
     </classpath>
</java>
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I take in arguments?

Comment: @John I updated the example but make sure to look through the docs. There are plenty of other examples.